# I want to make the squares in a row

Tags: android, bitmap, ondraw

Hi friends I want to make the squares in a row but I could not. My code is below. Can you help me?

```
int x=10,y=10;
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Paint p= new Paint();

    for(int i=1;i<6;i++)
    {
        canvas.drawBitmap(kutu, x,y, p);
        x +=50;
    }

    invalidate();
}
```

Thank you for helping.

Comment: It's generally good to show what your code is actually doing. I would help with this, but its a lot of work for me to run the code (whether through a compiler or in my head). More information is always better.

Comment: Please remove the invalidate() statement at the end of the onDraw

Comment: thanks blackbelt,I work since morning :)  Velox thanks for interest..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues:

- You need to reset `x` at the start of your `onDraw` method (Ideally, `x` should be a local variable, not a field)
- Remove the call to `invalidate`